# Calling optimize.newton function with multiple arguments throws a 'float object not callable' error

Tags: python, scipy

I am new to scipy, and the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
from scipy import optimize

def f(x, y):
    return x * x - 3 + y


def main():
   x0 = 0.1
    y = 1
    res = optimize.newton(f(x0,y), x0)
    print (res)
```

The error I receive is:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\zeros.py", line 144, in newton
    q0 = func(*((p0,) + args))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to supply a function as the first argument of `optimize.newton`. The guess `x0` for the independent parameter is supplied as the second argument and you can use `args` to supply constant parameters:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x * x - 3 + y

def main():
    x0 = .1
    y = 1
    res = optimize.newton(f, x0, args=(y,))
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question. args can be declared as a tuple, so if I presume I can simple declare: args0 = y, and then declare
res = optimize.newton(f, x0, args = args0)?

Comment: It has to be a tuple, so you have to declare `args0 = (y,)`. If you would have an additional parameter `z`, you could of course also add it as `args0 = (y, z)`.